# Trying to set the OnClickListner for a button

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a custome dialog box, but I'm getting errors when I call `OnClickListener` and it pass in a `OnClickListener()` class as the paramter. The error is

`The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})`

also it says in error message type view, shouldn't it be `Button`, could this be the issue?

code

```
// error message on line below
Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.action_settings);

// if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you show your imports

Comment: I'm going to guess you used the wrong `import`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a wrong import

Make sure you have

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Also you say

```
but I'm getting errors when I call setOnClickListener and itpass in a OnClickListener() class as the parameter.
```

You need to implement the `OnClickListener` interface. You use a annonymous inner class.

You can do as below

```
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override 
     public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
      }
});
```

Example:

http://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88&aaid=111

Comment: @DavidMays its a custom dialog with a button. so its is right

Comment: @DavidMays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417461/how-to-configure-custom-button-in-dialog and this http://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88&aaid=111

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that instead of implementing the onClick method in your activity, you can use the android:onClick attribute on the xml layout where the button is defined.

```
<Button
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/self_destruct"
 android:onClick="doSomething" />
```

Then implement the method doSomething in the activity:

```
 public void doSomething(View view) {
 // Kabloey
 }
```

For more details:

[Button description in Api reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)